# Samurize 1.64.3: Worked on Windows Vista, but not Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, samurize

Back when Windows Vista was my primary operating system, I had Samurize.  It worked very well on my desktop, but now, when I try to install it on Windows 7, it says that Samurize is only for Windows 2000, 2003, and XP.  What happened? Can I make it work?

32-bit, both Vista and 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install it in compatibility mode.